# Where clause to parents

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have for example two tables: Parent and Children. They have relations many-to-many between each other. Everything is working well, but I don't know how to use where clause in query builder for this.

My code:

```
    $parent = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Parent')->find(1);

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('c, p')
        ->from('AppBundle:Children', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('c.parents', 'p')
        ->where('p.id = :parent')
            ->setParameter('parent', $parent)
            ;

    $childrens = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This always return me null.

I know - I can use `$parent->getChildrens()`, but I would like use createQueryBuilder for `AppBundle:Children`.

How should the where clause look?

Comment: This should work, are you sure `$parent` has a value or you have data in your db?

Comment: check parent var because find(1) will look for id 1